# make: *** No rule to make target '-std=c99'

Tags: c, makefile

I've been reading so many make guide but I still cant make it work.
I'm trying to create a makefile that creates different programs, each program has its own source file (.c) but they all use the same header file (.h) nad all the files are in the same directory.

For now i have this:

```
CC   = gcc
CFLAGS   = -std=c99 -g -c -Wall
LFLAGS   = -std=c99 -g -c -Wall

OBJS    = nivel1.o nivel2.o nivel3.o nivel4.o nivel5.o nivel6.o my_shell.o
OUT = nivel1,nivel2,nivel3,nivel4,nivel5,nivel6,my_shell

OBJS0   = nivel1.o
SOURCE0 = nivel1.c
HEADER0 = my_shell.h
OUT0    = nivel1

OBJS1   = nivel2.o
SOURCE1 = nivel2.c
HEADER1 = my_shell.h
OUT1    = nivel2

OBJS2   = nivel3.o
SOURCE2 = nivel3.c
HEADER2 = my_shell.h
OUT2    = nivel3

OBJS3   = nivel4.o
SOURCE3 = nivel4.c
HEADER3 = my_shell.h
OUT3    = nivel4

OBJS4   = nivel5.o
SOURCE4 = nivel5.c
HEADER4 = my_shell.h
OUT4    = nivel5

OBJS5   = nivel6.o
SOURCE5 = nivel6.c
HEADER5 = my_shell.h
OUT5    = nivel6

OBJS6   = my_shell.o
SOURCE6 = my_shell.c
HEADER6 = my_shell.h
OUT6    = my_shell

all: nivel1 nivel2 nivel3 nivel4 nivel5 nivel6 my_shell

nivel1: $(OBJS0) $(LFLAGS)
    $(CC) -g $(OBJS0) -o $(OUT0)

nivel2: $(OBJS1) $(LFLAGS)
    $(CC) -g $(OBJS1) -o $(OUT1)

nivel3: $(OBJS2) $(LFLAGS)
    $(CC) -g $(OBJS2) -o $(OUT2)

nivel4: $(OBJS3) $(LFLAGS)
    $(CC) -g $(OBJS3) -o $(OUT3)

nivel5: $(OBJS4) $(LFLAGS)
    $(CC) -g $(OBJS4) -o $(OUT4)

nivel6: $(OBJS5) $(LFLAGS)
    $(CC) -g $(OBJS5) -o $(OUT5)

my_shell: $(OBJS6) $(LFLAGS)
    $(CC) -g $(OBJS6) -o $(OUT6)

nivel1.o: nivel1.c
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) nivel1.c -std=c99

nivel2.o: nivel2.c
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) nivel2.c -std=c99

nivel3.o: nivel3.c
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) nivel3.c -std=c99

nivel4.o: nivel4.c
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) nivel4.c -std=c99

nivel5.o: nivel5.c
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) nivel5.c -std=c99

nivel6.o: nivel6.c
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) nivel6.c -std=c99

my_shell.o: my_shell.c
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) my_shell.c -std=c99

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(OUT)
```

I've tried changing many things but nothing gets it to work,
any help would be appreciated!
PD: I need it to be std c99.

Comment: `nivel1: $(OBJS0) $(LFLAGS)` Why do you have `$(LFLAGS)` as a prerequisite?? That says, to build `nivel1` the target `-std=c99` needs to be built. It makes no sense.

Comment: You also use `$(FLAGS)` but `FLAGS` is never assigned.  Presumably you meant `$(CFLAGS)`?

Comment: sorry i still dont understand everything, what should i change?

Comment: Your `LFLAGS` is wrong too. It shouldn't include `-c`. And frankly, neither should `CFLAGS` if you setup your targets correctly.

Answer (score -1):

```
nivel1: $(OBJS0) $(LFLAGS)
    $(CC) -g $(OBJS0) -o $(OUT0)
```

is wrong. That is why `make` complains. You specified a dependance on `$(LFLAGS)` but that is not a file or a target, that is just a flag definition used at compile-time. You probably want:

```
nivel1: $(OBJS0)
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) -g $(OBJS0) -o $(OUT0)
```

---EDIT---(suggested by Kaylum)

`LFLAGS` has a wrong value. Since this command is a linking phase, neither `-std=c99`,  `-c` nor `-Wall` are usable.

Comment: Don't think that will quite work. That command is to link the final exec so is incompatible with at least the `-c` in `LFLAGS`.

Comment: @kaylum for sure, but dependencies are obviously wrong. Values is another problem.